# How do I declare list in python using for loop in one line?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
d = list()

for i in range(0,10):
    d.append(i)

print(d)
```

This does work, but is there way to write something like this:

```
d = list(for i in range(0,10) ) #produces a list of [0,1,2...9] 
d = [ d.append(for i in range(0,10))]
```

Is there one liner way to declare list in python using for loop inside it?

Comment: range() already returns a list

Comment: @LeiShi - Only in Python 2. This behavior is fixed in Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a way. What you're needing is called: [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

And you can do something like this:

```
d = [ i for i in range(0,10)]
```

which is similar to say:

```
d = list()
for i in range(0,10):
    d.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
d = list(range(10))
```

No for-loop needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list and range together:

```
>>>list(range(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python2:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Python3:

```
>>> list(range(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Because it consumes a lot of memory.

Comment: You may add the python3 version as well. That will be a more complete answer.